# How to describe a simple drawing?

Tags: vocabulary

Looking at the two images below how to you refer to each drawing style?

[image]

[image]

In general, what is the English name of this kind of artwork, black and white and without a grey shed? Like this.

[image]

Comment: The first apple I'd call a "vector" shape. The second, a "sketch". The third, perhaps a "line drawing". But there are probably lots of options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"line drawing" would seem to fit the first and last picture.

The second one uses a particular technique to create shading, "cross-hatching".